# Unsure of how to proceed with creating ec2-consisten-snapshot

Tags: perl, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, sh

I was just put on a task to try and debug and figure out why our ec2-consistent-snapshot script isn't working.

Our lead programmer followed this [blog post](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/05/ec2-consistent-snapshot-on-amazons-linux-ami/).

We have a `.sh` script that we'd like to take the snapshot and it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/opt/aws/bin/ec2-consistent-snapshot --aws-access-key-id MYACCESSKEY --aws-secret-access-key MYSECRETKEY --freeze-filesystem /vol --mysql --mysql-host localhost --mysql-socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --mysql-username USERNAME --mysql-password PASSWORD --description "Demo MySQL data volume: $(date +%c)" vol-MYVOL
```

If I run this by doing `sudo ./snapshot_script.sh` I get a single error:

`ec2-consistent-snapshot: ERROR: create_snapshot: File does not exist:  at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Net/Amazon/EC2.pm line 232`

I of course followed this error and line 232 in `EC2.pm` is this:

`my $ref = $xs->XMLin($xml);`

I have 0 perl experience and I don't know what this could be doing.

Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Net::Amazon::EC2](https://metacpan.org/source/MALLEN/Net-Amazon-EC2-0.20/lib/Net/Amazon/EC2.pm) that I'm looking at on CPAN has that line at 252, not 232 so perhaps you are not on the latest version.  Looking above that line, the program has attempted to do a "query to sign" using lots of the security parms.  I suspect there is a problem with the authentication keys you are using.  There is a debug flag, you might want to turn that on to generate more messages.

Comment: I actually just put replaced the older version .14 with .20 and got this error:
`Can't locate Net/Amazon/EC2/TagSet.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Net/Amazon/EC2.pm line 60.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Net/Amazon/EC2.pm line 60.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/aws/bin/ec2-consistent-snapshot line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/aws/bin/ec2-consistent-snapshot line 12.`

Comment: How do I add the debug flag? I commented out the last two includes and received the same error but this time on line 252.

Comment: At line 190 of the ec2-consistent-snapshot script you can see some logic to set the debug flag that is commented out.  What you need there is `Debug => 1,` to just hard code it in.

Comment: The program is expecting version 0.11 (see the 'require' at the top , so it might not be a good idea to upgrade.  And you have to use a tool to do the install like cpan, not copy and paste which it seems you may have done when you said "replace".

Comment: Ah thank you! How did I miss that I will try replacing it with version .11.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [this page](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#XMLin%28%29), you will see that `XMLin()` is a function of XML::Simple, and it takes a file as an argument.  So, `$xml` is presumably a variable that contains an xml file name.  That file does not exist.

The next step would be to trace the error back into the source code of ec2-consistent-snapshot, in order to see how it is calling XML::Simple and where the bad value gets passed in.

Comment: I understand that much. I just don't know why it wouldn't exist because in the blog post and other information I find online there isn't a mention of an xml file that needs installed.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the simplistic answer, but it wasn't clear from the question what you did and didn't understand.

Comment: It's okay I am a programmer so basic syntax is fairly self explanatory, but I have never dealth with Perl. It seems kind of unnecessary for me to have to since this isn't my code.